# DocuSign does not pass values to Salesforce

Tags: api, soap, salesforce, docusignapi

DocuSign doesn't pass values back into Salesforce. And Even doesn't give me any errors in the logs.

I used a Custom Field like source ID and MergeFieldXml tab option with the write-back = true. But it doesn't work.

Please advise what is wrong?

Merge fields are enabled for the DocuSign account.

My code example:

```
    global class AnnualContract
{    
    webService static string AM_SendToDocuSign(String id, string strObjType) 
   {   
    Docusign_API_Setting__c APISetting = Docusign_API_Setting__c.getInstance('API Settings');  
    String envelopeId = '';
    string DealerName = '';
    string DealerId = '';
    String accountId = APISetting.AccountId__c;
    String userId = APISetting.UserId__c;
    String password = APISetting.Password__c;
    String integratorsKey = APISetting.IntegratorsKey__c;
    String webServiceUrl = APISetting.WebServiceUrl__c;

    list<Lead> lstLead = new list<Lead>();
    list<Contact> lstContact = new list<Contact>();

    if(strObjType == 'Lead')
        {
            lstLead = [SELECT Name,Status,Email,FirstName,LastName,Owner.Name,Title,FROM Lead where id = : Id limit 1];
        }

     StaticResource objSR = [SELECT Id,name, SystemModStamp FROM StaticResource WHERE Name = 'AnnualContractPDF' LIMIT 1];

        String url_file_ref = '/resource/' + String.valueOf(((DateTime)objSR.get('SystemModStamp')).getTime())+ '/' + objSR.get('Name');  
        if(strObjType == 'Lead')
        {
            DealerName = lstLead[0].Name;
        }

    DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap dsApiSend = new DocuSignAPI.APIServiceSoap();
    dsApiSend.endpoint_x = webServiceUrl;

    //Set Authentication
    String auth = '<DocuSignCredentials><Username>'+ userId 
        +'</Username><Password>' + password 
        + '</Password><IntegratorKey>' + integratorsKey 
        + '</IntegratorKey></DocuSignCredentials>';
    System.debug('Setting authentication to: ' + auth);

    dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x = new Map<String, String>();
    dsApiSend.inputHttpHeaders_x.put('X-DocuSign-Authentication', 
                                     auth);

    DocuSignAPI.Envelope envelope = new DocuSignAPI.Envelope();
    envelope.Subject    = 'Please Sign this Contract' + lstLead[0].Name;
    envelope.EmailBlurb = 'This is my new eSignature service, it allows me to get your signoff without having to fax, scan, retype, refile and wait forever';
    envelope.AccountId  = accountId; 

     // Render the contract
    System.debug('Rendering the contract');       
    PageReference pageRef = new PageReference(url_file_ref);  
   Blob pdfBlob = pageRef.getContent();     

    DocuSignAPI.CustomField field = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField (); 
    field.Name = '##SFLead'; 
    field.Value = lstLead[0].Id;    //value of the external source Id
    field.Show = 'false';
    field.CustomFieldType = 'Text';      
    envelope.CustomFields = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfCustomField();
    envelope.CustomFields.CustomField = new DocuSignAPI.CustomField[1];
    envelope.CustomFields.CustomField[0] = field;

    // Document
    DocuSignAPI.Document document = new DocuSignAPI.Document();
    document.ID = 1;
    document.pdfBytes = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(pdfBlob);
    document.Name = 'Annual Contract';
    document.FileExtension = 'pdf';
    envelope.Documents = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfDocument();
    envelope.Documents.Document = new DocuSignAPI.Document[1];
    envelope.Documents.Document[0] = document;

    // Recipient        
    System.debug('Building up the recipient');
    DocuSignAPI.Recipient recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient();
    recipient.ID = 1;
    recipient.Type_x = 'Signer';
    recipient.RoutingOrder = 1;
    recipient.Email = lstLead[0].Email;
    recipient.UserName = lstLead[0].FirstName + ' ' + lstLead[0].LastName;

    recipient.RequireIDLookup = false;      

    envelope.Recipients = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfRecipient();
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient = new DocuSignAPI.Recipient[1];
    envelope.Recipients.Recipient[0] = recipient;

    // Tab
    DocuSignAPI.Tab tab1 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    tab1.Type_x = 'SignHere';
    tab1.RecipientID = 1;
    tab1.DocumentID = 1;
    tab1.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    tab1.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = '/t1/';
    tab1.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 100;


    DocuSignAPI.Tab tab2 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    tab2.Type_x = 'DateSigned';
    tab2.RecipientID = 1;
    tab2.DocumentID = 1;
    tab2.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    tab2.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = '/d1/';

    DocuSignAPI.Tab tab3 = new DocuSignAPI.Tab();
    tab3.CustomTabType = 'Text';
    tab3.Name = 'Title';
    tab3.Type_x = 'Custom';
    tab3.RecipientID = 1;
    tab3.DocumentID = 1;
    tab3.TabLabel = 'Title';
        if(strObjType == 'Lead')
        {
            if(lstLead[0].Title != null)
            {
                tab3.Value = ''+lstLead[0].Title+'';
            }  
        }
        else 
        {
            if(lstContact[0].Title != null)
            {
                tab3.Value = ''+lstContact[0].Title+'';
            }
        }
    tab3.CustomTabWidth=100;
    tab3.CustomTabRequired=false;
    tab3.CustomTabLocked=false;
    tab3.CustomTabDisableAutoSize=false;
    tab3.TemplateLocked=false;
    tab3.TemplateRequired=false;
    tab3.ConditionalParentLabel='';
    tab3.ConditionalParentValue='';
    tab3.SharedTab=true;
    tab3.RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange=false;
    tab3.ConcealValueOnDocument=false;
    tab3.AnchorTabItem = new DocuSignAPI.AnchorTab();
    tab3.AnchorTabItem.AnchorTabString = '/t2/';
    tab3.AnchorTabItem.XOffset = 42;
    tab3.AnchorTabItem.YOffset = -5;
    tab3.MergeFieldXml = '<mergeField><allowSenderToEdit>true</allowSenderToEdit><configurationType>salesforce</configurationType><path>Lead.Title</path><row>1</row><writeBack>true</writeBack></mergeField>';

    envelope.Tabs = new DocuSignAPI.ArrayOfTab();
    envelope.Tabs.Tab = new DocuSignAPI.Tab[3];
    envelope.Tabs.Tab[0] = tab1;        
    envelope.Tabs.Tab[1] = tab2;
    envelope.Tabs.Tab[2] = tab3;        

    System.debug('Calling the API');
    try {
      DocuSignAPI.EnvelopeStatus es = dsApiSend.CreateAndSendEnvelope(envelope);
      envelopeId = es.EnvelopeID;
      System.debug('Returned successfully, envelope id = ' + envelopeId );
        return '';
    } catch ( CalloutException e) {
  System.debug('Exception - ' + e );
      envelopeId = 'Exception - ' + e;
        return '';
}

    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest you provide more of your code.

Comment: @Alan Thank you for your comment. I have corrected my post. I hope it will help me and I will get  any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue with the DocuSign support. 
MergeFieldXml for SOAP should be like this:

```
tab3.MergeFieldXml ='<mergefieldconfig configversion="1.0" service="salesforce"><mergefield><writeenabled>true</writeenabled><sendercanedit>true</sendercanedit><queryfrom><obj><type>Lead</type><name>Lead</name><field><fieldtype>string</fieldtype><name>Title</name></field></obj></queryfrom></mergefield></mergefieldconfig>';
```